# Google Sheet Script Help - Store/write sheet ID, sheet name, cell location for a combined range

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a script to combine information from several tabs to a "master elements" tab. The script pull in rows tagged with the "MS" designation and it works great.   However, I also want to pull in the Sheetname, Sheet IT, and possiby a link to the source tab for each row with "MS".  That information is currently not stored in any of the source tabs.  Is that possible to do in script?

```
function combineData() {

  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Masterelements');

  // TO CLEAR DESTINATION TAB BEFORE REPOPULATION
  destination.getRange('A2:g1000').clearContent();


  //VARIABLE TO CYCLE THROUGH SPECIFIC SHEETS 
  var tabs = [
    'A-000',
    'B-123',
  ];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var s = 0; s < tabs.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[s]);
    Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow());
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Masterelements');
    var values = range.getValues();

    //Destination parameters - equivalent to destination.getRange(); 
    var numberOfColumns = 7;
    var numberOfRows = 1;
    var startColumn = 1;
    var startRow = 2;

    var count = 0

    // IDENTIFY THE FIRST ROW TO  CONSOLIDATE ITEMS
    var destRow = destination.getLastRow() + 1

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      Logger.log("i is now: " + i);
      Logger.log("Current row value: " + values[i][0])

      if (values[i][0] == 'MS') {
        Logger.log("*** Value found in cloumn: " + values[i][0] + "**** \n Count: " + i);
        count++;

        var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange((i + 1), 1, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);

        var destinationRange = destination.getRange(destRow, startColumn, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        destRow++;
        Logger.log("Next Destination row: " + destRow);
        rangeToCopy.copyTo(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "_I also want to pull in the Sheetname, Sheet IT, and possiby a link to the source tab for each row with "MS"._" Sheet name:`tabs[s]`. Sheet IT??, maybe you mean, SheetID = `getSheetId()` - say, `var sheetid=tabs[s].getSheetId();`. _possiby a link to the source tab for each row with "MS"_ - it's not clear what this actually means, please give an example of what a successful outcome would look like.

Comment: Sorry. This is my first time using script and I dont have a background in code.  Yes.  I meant sheetID.  How do I then get the script to output the sheetID along with the other items it is pulling from the other tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The OP supplied working code that copies rows, from two specific sheets, with a value of "MS" in Column A. However the OP also wanted:

- Sheetname
- Sheet ID
- *possiby a link to the source tab for each row with "MS"*

These are fairly easy to produce, but require too much information to explain in a comment.

I've taken the OP original code. I moved and/or edited some lines to make the code slightly more efficient. I've also added some lines of code to insert the Sheet name in Masterelements:Column H, the sheet ID in Masterelements:Column I and a link to the relevant sheet in Masterelements:Column J.

I think there is scope to make the code more efficient (specifically within the loops), but this is something that the OP can consider if the "real data" execution time is unreasonable.

```
function so54432164() {

  // setup the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get the spreadsheet URL - required for the hyperlink
  var ssurl = ss.getUrl();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: The url for this spreadsheet is "+ssurl);//DEBUG

  var destination = ss.getSheetByName('Masterelements');

  // CLEAR DESTINATION TAB BEFORE REPOPULATION
  // clear the entire destination sheet; this is more efficient that just clearing a nominated range
  destination.clearContents();

  // IDENTIFY THE first ROW TO  CONSOLIDATE ITEMS
  var destRow = destination.getLastRow() + 1

  //VARIABLE TO CYCLE THROUGH SPECIFIC SHEETS
  // note: no comma after the second tab name
  var tabs = [
    'A-000',
    'B-123'
  ];


  //Destination parameters 
  // note: brought this out of the "for" loop since only need to be declared once.
  var numberOfColumns = 7;
  var numberOfRows = 1;
  var startColumn = 1;
  var startRow = 2;
  // used for destination.getRange();  


  // Loop through the sheets  
  for (var s = 0; s < tabs.length; s++) {

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[s]);

    // create variables to get the Sheet Name and the sheetID
    var sheetname = sheet.getSheetName();
    var sheetID = sheet.getSheetId();
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet: "+sheetname+", SheetID: "+sheetID);//DEBUG

    // get the data: the var 'range' was never used, so we can just call the values direct to 'values'.
    var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();


    //LOOP through the rows in the target sheet
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

      //Logger.log("DEBUG: row = " + i+", and Column A value: " + values[i][0]);//DEBUG

      // test for "MS" in Column A
      if (values[i][0] == 'MS') {

        //Logger.log("DEBUG: Found MS, Count: " + i);//DEBUG

        // define the range to copy 
        var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange((i + 1), 1, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the rangetocopy is "+rangeToCopy.getA1Notation()); //DEBUG

        // Define the destination range      
        var destinationRange = destination.getRange(destRow, startColumn, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: the destination range "+destinationRange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

        // copy the source to the target
        rangeToCopy.copyTo(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

        // create a variable for the hyperlink formula
        var formula = '=HYPERLINK("' + ssurl + '#gid=' + sheetID + '")';
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the formula = "+formula);//DEBUG

        // create a variable for the extra data: Sheet name, Sheet ID, and the hyperlink to the sheet.
        var extradata = [
          [sheetname, sheetID, formula]
        ];

        //define the destination range and set the values
        destination.getRange(destRow, numberOfColumns + 1, numberOfRows, 3).setValues(extradata);

        // increment the destination row
        destRow++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```